# Cross compile ncurses for armv7

Tags: linux, makefile, compiler-errors, cross-compiling, armv7

I use arm-linux-gnueabihf cross-compiling ncurses,
An error occurred at the "make install" step

```
strip: Unable to recognise the format of the input file `/home/chumeng/cross_compile/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-tic'
```

Here's my steps

```bash
$ ./configure --prefix=/home/chumeng/cross_compile/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --with-shared --with-normal --without-debug --without-ada --enable-widec --enable-pc-files --with-cxx-binding --with-cxx-shared --enable-ext-colors --enable-ext-mouse --enable-overwrite
configure: WARNING: If you wanted to set the --build type, don't use --host.
    If a cross compiler is detected then cross compile mode will be used.
...a lot of "checking"
** Configuration summary for NCURSES 6.4 20221231:

       extended funcs: yes
       xterm terminfo: xterm-new

        bin directory: /home/chumeng/cross_compile/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin
        lib directory: /home/chumeng/cross_compile/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib
    include directory: /home/chumeng/cross_compile/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/include
        man directory: /home/chumeng/cross_compile/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/share/man
   terminfo directory: /home/chumeng/cross_compile/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/share/terminfo
 pkg-config directory: /home/chumeng/cross_compile/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/pkgconfig
 
$ make -j32
 ...
 
$ make install
 ... a lot of "installing"
( cd progs && make DESTDIR="" RPATH_LIST="/home/chumeng/cross_compile/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib" install )
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/chumeng/ncurses/ncurses-6.4/progs'
/usr/bin/install -c -s tic     /home/chumeng/cross_compile/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/`echo tic|       sed 's/$//'|sed 's,^,arm-linux-gnueabihf-,'|sed 's/$//'`
strip: Unable to recognise the format of the input file `/home/chumeng/cross_compile/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-tic'
/usr/bin/install: strip process terminated abnormally
make[1]: *** [Makefile:219: install.progs] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/chumeng/ncurses/ncurses-6.4/progs'
make: *** [Makefile:136: install] Error 2
```

Comment: You need to convince the build system of ncurses to use `arm-linux-gnueabihf-strip` instead of the regular `strip` when it's stripping your cross-compiled ARM binaries.  Or just convince it to skip that step.  You can see if there are any configuration options or environment variables related to it by running `./configure --help`.  If not, you might have to patch ncurses: not every project was designed with cross-compiling in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I referred to `./configure --help` and added the `--without-progs` option, and then the compilation was successful.